# grails 2 integration test

Tags: grails, integration, integration-testing

I have created an Integration Test in Grails 2.x with the purpouse of testing several controllers in order to simulate a complete user flow within a Web App.

First I saved two simple domain object records, instantiating two controller instances within my test case. This two simple classes are:
- Category (category of a product) and 
- Store (mini market where products are sale) 
I wrote two testing methods to control the controller instances (StoreController and CategoryController) and worked fine, one category record was created and several store records as well.

Then, I wrote a third method to try to save a Product record. This record must reference a Category. So, I take the category instance from previous methods and try to pass it to the ProductController among the other Product parameters.

For an unknown reason, I'm only able to create Product records through the web app instance typing the data in the web browsers, but not by the test class code.
I think the problem issue is with the relationship between Product and Category, but I could not figured out how I should pass the parameters to the ProductController from my test case in order to create a new Product record.

This is my Product class:

```
class Product {

    int id

    String barCode
    String shortDesc
    String longDesc
    String format

    Category category
    static belongsTo = [category: Category]    

    //static hasManySurveyRecord = [surveyRecord: SurveyRecord]


    static constraints = {

            id        editable: false
            barCode   blank: false, nullable: false, maxSize: 64
            shortDesc blank: false, nullable: false, maxSize: 32
            longDesc  blank: false, nullable: false, maxSize: 128
            category  blank: false
    }

    static mapping = {
        table 'product_catalog'
        version false

        columns {
                id column: 'id'
                barCode column: 'bar_code'
                shorDesc column: 'short_desc'
                longDesc column: 'long_desc'
                format column: 'format'
        }
    }

    String toString() {

        return longDesc
    }
}
```

This is my Category class:

```
class Category {

    int id

    String description


    static hasManyProduct = [products: Product]


    static constraints = {

            id            editable: false
            description   blank: false, nullable: false, maxSize: 64
    }

    static mapping = {
        table 'categories'
        version false

        columns {
                id column: 'id'
                description column: 'description'
        }
    }

    String toString() {

        return description
    }
}
```

This is my integration test for this app:

```
static transactional = false

static storeList  = []
static storesData = []

static categoryIns
static categoryData = []

static productIns  = new Product()
static productData = []




@Before
void setup() {

    storesData.add([zipCode: 926260001, address: "first test avenue, first city, CA"    , description: "first testing store"])
    storesData.add([zipCode: 926260002, address: "second test avenue, second city, CA"  , description: "second testing store"])
    storesData.add([zipCode: 926260003, address: "third test avenue, third city, CA"    , description: "third testing store"])
    storesData.add([zipCode: 926260004, address: "fourth test avenue, fourth city, CA"  , description: "fourth testing store"])
    storesData.add([zipCode: 926260005, address: "fifth test avenue, fifth city, CA"    , description: "fifth testing store"])
    storesData.add([zipCode: 926260006, address: "sixth test avenue, sixth city, CA"    , description: "sixth testing store"])
    storesData.add([zipCode: 926260007, address: "seventh test avenue, seventh city, CA", description: "seventh testing store"])
    storesData.add([zipCode: 926260008, address: "eighth test avenue, eighth city, CA"  , description: "eighth testing store"])

    categoryData = [description: "testing category"]

    productData = [barCode: "0114B", shorDesc: "The short testing description", longDesc: "The long testing description ....", format: "1 LT"]
}



@Test
void _01__createStores() {

    def storeCtl = new StoreController()

    (0..7).each { i ->

            def model = storeCtl.create()

            assert model.storeInstance != null

            storeCtl.response.reset()

            storeCtl.params.putAll( storesData.get(i) )
            storeCtl.save()

            assert Store.count() == (i+1)

    }

    storeList.addAll( Store.list() )

    assert storeList.size() == Store.list().size()
}

@Test
void _02__createCategory() {

    // Test if there is a previous store list created
    assert storeList.size() == Store.list().size()

    def categoryCtl = new CategoryController()

    def model = categoryCtl.create()

    assert model.categoryInstance != null

    categoryCtl.response.reset()

    categoryCtl.params.putAll( categoryData )
    categoryCtl.save()

    assert Category.count() == 1

    categoryIns = Category.list()[0]
}

@Test
void _03__createProduct() {

    // Test if there is a previous store list created
    assert storeList.size() == Store.list().size()
    // Test if there is a previous category created
    assert categoryIns != null
    assert categoryIns.id > 0

    def productCtl = new ProductController()

    def model = productCtl.create()

    assert model.productInstance != null

    productCtl.response.reset()

    productData.put("category", [id: categoryIns.id])
    productData.put("category.id", categoryIns.id)
    productCtl.params.putAll( productData )
    //productCtl.params.category = Category.get(categoryIns.id) 
    productCtl.save()

    assert Product.count() == 1
}
```

This is my ProductController code extract:

```
def save() {
    def productInstance = new Product(params)
    if (!productInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "create", model: [productInstance: productInstance])
        return
    }

    flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'product.label', default: 'Product'), productInstance.id])
    redirect(action: "show", id: productInstance.id)
}
```

Comment: Sorry,
The assertion that fails is "assert Product.count() == 1" in the test method "void _03__createProduct()". It's just the last one.
Thanks

Comment: After `productCtl.save()` check the errors of your bean: `println productCtl.errors`

Comment: Or use `.save(failOnError:true)` to throw exceptions when the validation or saving fails.

Answer (score 0):

Both recomendations worked fine. After hours and hours trying to figure out what were going wrong, thanks to you I saw clear my silly silly mistake: a field "shortDesc" was misspelled as "shorDesc".
So, one little tip to my book has been written.
Thank you very much!